# Adding 3 columns and pasting results in a different column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Excel and I want to add 3 of the columns and put the sum in another column of the same sheet using VBA. However, it seems like the code runs it to the very end (row 1048576) even though my data only has 2000+ rows. When I defined the table, I defined it like its from column A to column R so I don't know how to modify the code so it will only go through how many other rows there are in the data.

You can see image below that it literally ran to the bottom of the sheet, which is not what I am asking for. The 3 columns are values only like 1, 2 and 3. And why I set up data as table is because every week I get new data with different # of rows. I tried to implement different formulas but it looks like the code will run to the very end of the column instead of stopping at the end of the data. So it is clearly not an issue about the formula but the way I am setting up the data range or the table.

```
Sub Prem_Inc()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("TB")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
      Worksheets("TB").Cells(i, 13).Value = "=Sum(RC[-3], RC[-2], RC[-1])"
    Next i

    With Range("M2", "M" & lRow)
      .Style = "Currency"
      .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.0_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
      .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End With

    With Range("P2", "R" & lRow)
      .Style = "Currency"
      .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.0_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
      .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the data you want to sum? You state in the question that you have data in Columns `A` to `D` but you are using column `G` to set your maximum row number and then you sum in Column `M` the values of Columns `J`, `K` and `L`.

Comment: Sorry, table is set up from Column A to Column R. I mis-spelled it. Every column have the same amount of data (same # of rows). So I don't think if  I set up the last row to be G or B will make a difference which I have tried. And yes, M is the sum of J, K and L.

Comment: Quick fixes/test, you need to define the worksheet when using `Rows.Count`, so switch it to `lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row`.  Also, step through your macro with `F8`, and after it sets the last row, hover the mouse over `lRow` and it should show you the value that is.  Also, perhaps add `.Select` after both `With Range()` lines. (Note that using `.Select` is generally frowned upon, it can help when stepping through a macro and lets you see the range you're working with).

Comment: Thank you but it gave me the same result so it was still trying to go through the whole column without taking account of # of rows in column G or any other columns I have tried. When I press F8, it has yellow pointer at next i and evaluates as how I have described above.

Comment: What is the value you get for `lRow`?

Comment: The $2,005 entry is in row 2100 and so it keeps calculating as in the image. And this is something very odd. I have other arithmetic operation using vba and they all work just fine and I am trying to do this last step but it fails, so it is quite frustrating.

Comment: Using `lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row` will assign lrow to be the last row in your table, not the last used row.  Are you sure that your code "literally ran to the bottom of the sheet" or did it just go to the bottom of the table?

Comment: @A.S.H. it skips that when I pressed F8.

Comment: @YowE3K, the way I set up my data range as the table is from column A to R, so that will mean the same thing? It went to the bottom of the table which is the last row of the excel sheet. If I only set up my data range to be 2100 rows from column A to R, next week, if I dump in 2500 rows, will it capture or do I need to resize? This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @YowE3K I don't understand your comment but please see my second image if it helps.

Comment: I tried to resize my table to be A2100-R2100 and it works but my concern is that next week if I dump new data and if range if more or less than that, do I need to resize everyweek?

Comment: This appears to just be Excel's normal behaviour in a table.  If you enter a formula (or a formula masquerading as a `Value`) into a table and there is nothing in that column already, it will copy that formula into all rows for that column.

Comment: You can get around it by putting a dummy value of, perhaps, "x" in cell M2 and then, when you run your macro, it will work correctly.  (Or as correctly as it can with the unqualified `Range`s etc.)  And it will continue to run correctly in the future.

Comment: I tried to run 'lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row' and it gives me 2100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to just be Excel's normal behaviour in a table. If you enter a formula (or a formula masquerading as a Value) into a table and there is nothing in that column already, it will copy that formula into all rows for that column.

This code will avoid the issue by just writing the formula to the specific rows.  (It might still have issues if row 2 is the last row of data, but I assume that won't be an issue for you.)

```
Sub Prem_Inc()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("TB")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "M"), .Cells(lRow, "M"))
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(RC[-3], RC[-2], RC[-1])"
            .Style = "Currency"
            'Why set NumberFormat twice??
            .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.0_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End With

        With .Range(.Cells(2, "P"), .Cells(lRow, "R"))
            .Style = "Currency"
            .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.0_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @sc1324 I was going to suggest a workaround of making the code writing a dummy constant value into the column first (which would stop Excel populating the whole column with the first formula entered) but then realised that applying the formula to more than one row at once also avoided the issue.